# Java to Cpp Code Conversion , problem regarding static and new keyword

Tags: java, c++, object, static, new-operator

```
public class ProblemDef {
        private static WFG1 w12;
        }
 public ProblemDef()
        {
            w12 = new WFG1(1,23,2);
}
```

If I write this in C++ as follows

```
class ProblemDef{
         private:
                static WFG1* w12;
         public:
                ProblemDef(){
                w12=new WFG1(1,23,2);
                }
};
```

It shows an error, how can I proceed. What is the equivalent of a "new "keyword-based object declaration in C++? How is static declaration of objects done in C++?

Comment: Which error does it show?

Comment: Unfortunately, drawing parallels between two completely unrelated and different languages can be counterproductive.

Comment: Java and C++ are completely different languages and although they use some of the same words in their grammar, they don't mean the same thing. You cannot transfer knowledge of one language to the other. You have to learn each on its own.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you should use `new` as little as possible because you also need to `delete` what you've `new`ed, which is tricky to get right. There's no need for `new` at all here:

```
class ProblemDef{
    private:
        static WFG1 w12;      // no pointer

    public:
        ProblemDef() {}
};

WFG1 ProblemDef::w12(1,23,2); // initialization of the static variable
```

This makes all instances of `ProblemDef` to share the same `WFG1`.

If you *really* want a new `WFG1` for each instance of `ProblemDef`, don't make it `static`.

Answer (score 0):

First lets start with what the keyword "new" is doing. New is creating an object and is doing this by allocating memory. new in Java and C++ relatively do the same purpose of allocating memory however, you need to be careful when allocating memory in C++.

In C++ there is no automatic garbage collection like there is in Java.

All that "Automatic garbage collection" means is that in java when you call the keyword new there is underlying compiler code that is deleting objects created with key word new that your program is no longer using.

You the programmer are in charge of creating "De constructor's" in C++. which is the equivalent to code that will run and detect if a object is no longer being used and should be deleted.

A word to the wise, Deconstructors can be tricky so I always tell new C++ programmers to have a "Destroy" method. This method goes through and deletes all objects in an algorithmic way (For example when you are done with a linked list the destroy function will loop through and delete each node in the linked list).

Hope this helps!